# Computer software is Word document

Tags: windows

I have accidentally deleted 4000 words from a Word document with a view to copying them into another document. They are from an important document which has a deadline on it. I can find them nowhere and I am about to have a nervous breakdown.

Comment: Did you save the Document after you deleted the words? Also, which version of Windows are you using? XP, 7, 8, etc.

Comment: The version of Word might be useful, too.

Comment: Did you have track changes enabled?

Comment: Restore from backup?

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you used the  <kbd>Ctrl ⌃</kbd>   <kbd>C</kbd>  copy command with a view to later using   <kbd>Ctrl ⌃</kbd>   <kbd>V</kbd>  to paste. If, in the meantime you forgot & copied something else, the original buffer would just be overwritten by the new one; or if you rebooted, then it would be empty.

Your only recourse, in that case, would be an earlier saved version, or your backup.

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't backing up files periodically, you may still be able to restore a file to a prior version using Microsoft's [Volume Snapshot Service (VSS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shadow_Copy), aka "shadow copy". If you had previously saved the file with the information you need within it, right-click on the file, choose **Properties**, then click on the **Previous Versions** tab. If there are any previous versions stored on the system by VSS, you will be able to restore the file to its state in a previous version. If you added some other information to the new version that you need to retain, it would probably be best to copy the latest version to another file first.